# zsh: How to get value of variable based on a another variable?

Tags: zsh, variable

I think a example would best explain what I need

```
_v1="windows"

_v2_windows="/mnt/d"
_v2_osx="/Volumes/d"

echo $_v2_`echo $_v1`
```

I want to echo the value of `_v2_windows` but using `_v1` to determine which of the two `v2`s to get.

I know can use a `case` statement to solve the problem but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `zsh`:

- `${(P)varname}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is stored in `$varname`. So if `$varname` contains `var`, `${(P)varname}` expands to the same thing as `$var`.
- `${(e)var}` expands to the content of `$var` but also performs parameter expansions, command substitution and arithmetic expansion within. So if `$var` contains `$othervar`, `${(e)var}` expands to the same thing as `$othervar`.
- You can nest variable expansion operators, so things like `${(P)${var:-something}}` work
- `${:-content}` is one way to have a parameter expansion expand to arbitrary text (here `content`)

(see [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) for details)

So you could do:

```
_v1=windows
_v2_windows=/mnt/d
printf '%s\n' ${(P)${:-_v2_$_v1}}
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(e)${:-\$_v2_$_v1}}
```

Or do it in two steps:

```
varname=_v2_$_v1
printf '%s\n' ${(P)varname}
```

Or:

```
expansions_to_evaluate=\$_v2_$_v1

printf '%s\n' ${(e)expansions_to_evaluate}
```

Or you could use the standard POSIX syntax:

```
eval 'printf "%s\n" "${_v2_'"$_v1"'}"'
```

Beware that if  the value of `$_v1` is not under your control, all those amount to an arbitrary command injection vulnerability, you'd need to sanitize the value first.

Also note that `zsh` supports associative arrays (and has long before `bash`), so you can do:

```
typeset -A mnt
mnt=(
  windows /mnt/d
  osx     /Volumes/d
)
os=windows
printf '%s\n' $mnt[$os]
```

Which would be a lot more legible, and wouldn't have any of those security implications.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '%s\n' "${(P)$(echo "_v2_$_v1")}"
```

alternatively

```
var=_v2_$_v1
printf '%s\n' "${(P)var}"
```

In both cases, the parameter expansion flag `(P)` is used to expand the name inside `${...}` into the name of the actual variable that we'd like to get the value of.

This is *similar* to variable indirection with `${!...}` in the `bash` shell.